# iTunes not accepting me to download apps from the App Store

Tags: itunes, ipad, macos, ios-appstore, apple-id

I was bought an iPad yesterday. I'm actually a 12 year old and want to download Subway Surfers but can't. I always have internet but whenever I try my account is not verified. What's the step foward guys?

Comment: Welcome to the community Mark. To try and help you we need more information. Can you explain what steps you're actually taking, whether you have a new or existing Apple ID, etc.

Comment: A screenshot of the error message would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is the account in your name or a parent/guardian?

There maybe restrictions set on the account, or the email address or password maybe incorrect.

As Subway Surfers contains in-app purchases this may also be restricted.

I would recommend speaking with your parent or guardian to get the issue resolved.

Although more information would allow use to help resolve the issue.